# Jquery Calender MinDate

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script :

```
    $(function () {
        var now = new Date();
        $("#dd").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', minDate: now});
        $("#df").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', minDate: "dd" });
    });
```

here `dd` minDate is current date, also i want to add that minDate in `df` gonna be the selected date in `dd` field, so i have make serval try but it didn't worked any idea here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the first datepicker's [`onSelect`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-onSelect) event, and update the second datepicker accordingly:

```
$("#dd").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', minDate: now,
    onSelect:function(selectedDate) {
        $("#df").datepicker("option","minDate",selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/TVNGW/)

Comment: Dosn't work, when i click on df filed the calander is not showen any more